# Subject of the formula involving Matrices

Tags: matrices

I have the following formula:

$$(x_2) ^{\intercal}Fx = 0$$

where $\intercal$ denotes transpose

$F$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, 
$x$ is a $3\times 1$ matrix.

I want to put $(x_2)^{\intercal}$ as the subject of the formula, what should be done please?

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to do exactly? I don't understand the sentence "I want to put $x^T$ subject of the formula".

Comment: Do you mean you want to "isolate" $x$?

Comment: That added $\;2\;$ makes things even more confusing

Comment: @HowDoIMath Thank you for your comments and edit, (as i am new to this hehe). Basically I have the above formula used in multi view geometry. I want to place the matrix $x'^T$ as subject of the formula since I have F and x. x' ([prime) is another 3D point...

Comment: @Timbuc sorry, removed the 2, wanted to show that the first x and second x matrices are different. Denoted them using a x' and x now.

Comment: Them you should have put the $2$ as a subscript like $x_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make $x_2$ the subject of the formula, you can transpose first 
$$x^TF^Tx_2=0$$
and express the equation as the inner product of two vectors (which will be of size $9$ in your case)
$$vec(F)^T(x\otimes x_2)=0$$
where the $vec$ operation on a matrix is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and the Kronecker $\otimes$ product is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

For the $3\times 3$ matrix, we can work things out by hand (although it is a bit long winded)
$$F=\left(\begin{matrix}f_{11} & f_{12} & f_{13} \\f_{21} & f_{22} & f_{23} \\f_{31} & f_{32} & f_{33}\end{matrix}\right)$$
and vectors $x=[x(1),x(2),x(3)]$ and $x_2=[x_2(1),x_2(2),x_2(3)]$
 the equation is
$$[f_{11}\ f_{21} \ f_{31}\ f_{12}\ f_{22} \ f_{32} \ f_{13}\ f_{23} \ f_{33}]\left[\begin{matrix}x(1)x_2(1)\\x(1)x_2(2)\\x(1)x_2(3)\\x(2)x_2(1)\\x(2)x_2(2)\\x(2)x_2(3)\\x(3)x_2(1)\\x(3)x_2(2)\\x(3)x_2(3)\end{matrix}\right]=0$$

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I have followed the steps and I think i've understood most of it. However I haven't understood the last part... The equation i'm looking for needs to be: $x_2$ = bla bla bla. Didn't really understand how variable y got involved

Comment: @LukeZammit: It was an extra set of terms I introduced - I think it has caused more confusion, so I will edit my answer (and remove the extra bits).

Comment: thanks for the edit. Please excuse my understanding in this field, However I can't see how $x_2$ is made subject of the formula? The terms in $x_2$ in my case are all unknowns and i'm trying to find them..

Comment: @LukeZammit Prior to my edit, I expressed the problem as $Ax_2=y$, where $A$ is a matrix in terms of the elements of $F$ and vector $x$ which are known, but $y$ which is unknown (but whose elements sum to $0$). If there was any additional condition we could put on $y$, such that the elements are all $0$, then it would be straightforward to find $x_2$.

Comment: Just to see if i've understood correctly. If i start with $$(x_2) ^{\intercal}Fx = 0$$ and even though I have a 3x3 matrix with values for F and a 3x1 matrix for x, I cannot find values for $x_2$ ?

Comment: @LukeZammit Because $Fx$ is a vector, you will not find a *unique* solution for $x_2$. If, however, you had three equations, $(x_2)^TF_1x=0$ , $(x_2)^TF_2x=0$ and $(x_2)^TF_3x=0$  and the vectors $F_1x$, $F_2x$ and $F_3x$ were linearly independent, then you could find a unique solution to $x_2$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying all this.